# Randomize a column and fill in 3 more columns following a set ruleset

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Step 1: I am trying to make a sheet that uses a macro button to randomize a column of numbers (stations) 1 through 15.

Step 2: I need the next 3 columns after the randomized one to follow the rule where, in each column, every station from the previous column has 5 station numbers added to it, with the stations 11 - 15 starting back at 1, 2, etc.

I am including a screenshot of a sample sheet to show what I am trying to do with both a starting column set and an example of what I want the finished result to look like. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you don't need VBA.

Use this formula to retrieve randomized start values in `A2`: `=SORTBY(SEQUENCE(15),RANDARRAY(15))`

`SEQUENCE` returns numbers from 1 to 15 - they are sorted by an random array of 15 values.

Then use the following formula in `B2`: `=IF(A2#<11,A2#+5,A2#-10)` and copy it to `C2` and `D2`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works in Excel 2021 Pro as well, but every time you edit/change any cell on the sheet, it re-randomizes the numbers, thus the reason I was hoping for a macro button that would run the feature once on command only and hold the values permanently.

Answer (score 1):

### Shuffle and Apply Rules Using `Mod`

**Excel**

```
=LET(rCount,15,cCount,3,nShift,5,
    s,SORTBY(SEQUENCE(rCount),RANDARRAY(rCount)),
REDUCE(s,SEQUENCE(cCount),LAMBDA(rr,c,
    HSTACK(rr,MOD(s+c*nShift-1,rCount)+1))))
```

[image]

**VBA**

```vb
Sub ShuffleTEST()
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "F2"
    Const ROWS_COUNT As Long = 15
    Const COLS_COUNT As Long = 3
    Const NUM_SHIFT As Long = 5
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim Data(): Data = ws.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & ROWS_COUNT & ")")
    ShuffleColumn Data
    
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To ROWS_COUNT, 1 To COLS_COUNT + 1)

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To ROWS_COUNT
        For c = 1 To COLS_COUNT
            Data(r, c + 1) = (Data(r, 1) + c * NUM_SHIFT - 1) Mod ROWS_COUNT + 1
        Next c
    Next r

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range(FIRST_CELL).Resize(ROWS_COUNT, COLS_COUNT + 1)
 
    rg.Value = Data
 
End Sub


Sub ShuffleColumn(ByRef Data As Variant)
    
    Dim LB As Long: LB = LBound(Data, 1)
    
    Dim Temp As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = UBound(Data, 1) To LB + 1 Step -1
        j = Int((i - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB)
        Temp = Data(i, 1): Data(i, 1) = Data(j, 1): Data(j, 1) = Temp
    Next i

End Sub
```